# Define a huge hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, hex, size

I am working with a function `cksumcrc32(init, (unsigned char *) &data, len);`. The problem is that variable data is quite big, in hexadecimal is: `0x0020b3801005064000007d8000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000`, in terms of bytes, it is 36 bytes long. I am trying to define the variable in c++, but errors like "integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type" appear. I would appreciate it if someone could help me defining this big variable, I have looked at similar threads but I have not seen help for such big variables.
Thanks.

Comment: There are "big integer" libraries around which can help you with numbers larger than what the C++ standard types allows (the largest is currently `long long` which typically is 64 bits).

Comment: Does your platform support a 36 byte integer?  Can it be held in a `std::array<std::byte, 36>` or `std::vector<std::byte>`?  If you are using **clang**, you can use the `_ExtInt` which can hold a 288-bit integer.

Comment: Looking closer, it seems that what you really want is an *array* or *vector* of unsigned bytes, where each of the 36 bytes in the number is stored in one element each.

Comment: Yes, I think that an array of unsigned bytes where I enter the 36 bytes' values would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an `array` of these bytes (or a `vector`) in the format:

```cpp
std::vector<std::byte> arr;
arr.push_back(byte);
```

With this, you can individually add bytes of the number into this vector, allowing the integer to be as large as you want.